# SAS Retain not working for 1 string variable

Tags: sas, concatenation, retain

The below code doesn't seem to be working for the variable all_s when there is more than 1 record with the same urn. Var1,2,3 work fine but that one doesn't and I cant figure out why. I am trying to have all_s equal to single_var1,2,3 concatenated with no spaces if it's first.urn but I want it to be

all_s = all_s + ',' + single_var1 + single_var2 + single_var3

when it's not the first instance of that urn.

```
data dataset_2;
    set dataset_1;
    by URN;
    retain count var1 var2 var3 all_s;
    format var1 $40. var2 $40. var3 $40. all_s $50.;
    if first.urn then do;
        count=0;
        var1 = ' ';
        var2 = ' ';
        var3 = ' ';
        all_s = ' ';
    end;
    var1 = catx(',',var1,single_var1);
    var2 = catx(',',var2,single_var2);
    var3 = catx(',',var3,single_var3);

    all_s = cat(all_s,',',single_var1,single_var2,single_var3);

    count = count+1;
    if first.urn then do;
        all_s = cat(single_var1,single_var2,single_var3);
    end;
run;
```

Comment: What is the length of `single_var1-single_var3` that is coming from `dataset_1` ?

Comment: Do you want a single row output for each `URN` group ?  If you do not, your output data will show the intermediate `var1-var3` and `all_s` concatenations.

Comment: I forgot about if last.urn then output; thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all_s` is not large enough to contain the concatenation if the total length of the `var1-var3` values within the group exceeds `$50`.  Such a scenario seems likely with `var1-var3` being `$40`.

I recommend using the `length` function to specify variable lengths.  `format` will create a variable of a certain length as a side effect.

`catx` removes blank arguments from the concatenation, so if you want spaces in the concatenation when you have blank `single_varN` you won't be able to use `catx`

A requirement that specifies a concatenation such that non-blank values are stripped and blank values are a single blank will likely have to fall back to the old school `trim(left(…` approach

**Sample code**

```
data have;
  length group 8 v1-v3 $5;
  input group (v1-v3) (&);
datalines;
1  111  222  333
1  .    444  555
1  .    .    666
1  .    .    .
1  777  888  999
2  .    .    .
2  .    b    c
2  x    .    z
run;

data want(keep=group vlist: all_list);
  length group 8 vlist1-vlist3 $40 all_list $50;
  length comma1-comma3 comma $2;

  do until (last.group);
    set have;
    by group;

    vlist1 = trim(vlist1)||trim(comma1)||trim(left(v1));
    vlist2 = trim(vlist2)||trim(comma2)||trim(left(v2));
    vlist3 = trim(vlist3)||trim(comma3)||trim(left(v3));

    comma1 = ifc(missing(v1), ' ,', ',');
    comma2 = ifc(missing(v2), ' ,', ',');
    comma3 = ifc(missing(v3), ' ,', ',');

    all_list = 
      trim(all_list)
      || trim(comma)
      || trim(left(v1))
      || ','
      || trim(left(v2))
      || ','
      || trim(left(v3))
    ;

    comma = ifc(missing(v3),' ,',',');
  end;
run;
```

**Reference**

SAS has operators and multiple functions for string concatenation

- `||` concatenate
- `cat` concatenate
- `catt` concatenate, trimming (remove trailing spaces) of each argument
- `cats` concatenate, stripping (remove leading and trailing spaces) of each argument
- `catx` concatenate, stripping each argument and delimiting
- `catq` concatenate with delimiter and quote arguments containing the delimiter

From [SAS 9.2 documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002257076.htm)

> **Comparisons**
>
> The results of the CAT, CATS, CATT, and CATX functions are usually equivalent to results that are produced by certain combinations of the concatenation operator (||) and the TRIM and LEFT functions. However, the default length for the CAT, CATS, CATT, and CATX functions is different from the length that is obtained when you use the concatenation operator. For more information, see [Length of Returned Variable](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/a002257076.htm#a003124145).
>
> **Note:**   In the case of variables that have missing values, the concatenation produces different results. See [Concatenating Strings That Have Missing Values](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/a002257076.htm#a003253722).

Answer (score 1):

Some example data would be helpful, but I'm going to give it a shot and ask you to try

```
all_s = cat(strip(All_s),',',single_var1,single_var2,single_var3);
```

Comment: It works! Why though? I wanted to keep space for when single_var1,2,3 are blank.

Comment: For the `all_s` case of each `single_var1-single_var3` being blank do you want 3 spaces ?  Should the `var1` contain a space when consecutive rows in the group has a blank `single_var1` ?

Comment: Yeah that's how it was for var1 if they are all blank then then it will be , , , 
In case of all_s I wanted '   ,   ,   ,   ' If they were all blank for example

Comment: Now you're adding a comma in front of every row except the first. If you instead added the comma at the end of every row except  the last, the comma would protect the spaces from the strip function.